# fetch data using ajax in php

Tags: php, ajax

I have two tables in my database first one id and the other one text.

I can fetch the data from db like this way

this is index.php file

```
<?php include "config.php"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>

    <?php
    $result = $db->query("select * from veri ORDER  BY id DESC ");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
      echo '<li id="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->text.'</li>';
    }


    ?>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I am required to check the database every five seconds if a new item inserted or not.
I am using this code below.But It doesnt work.I have no idea what is wrong ?can you please help and thank in advance

ajax.js file

```
$(function () {

    $ajaxLoad = function () {

        var lastid = $("ul li:first").attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {"lastid": lastid},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    $("#result").html(result);

                }
                else{
                    $("ul").prepend(result.data);
                }
            }

        });
    }
    setInterval("ajaxLoad()",5000);

});
```

this ajax.php file

```
<?php

require "config.php";

if ($_POST) {

    $lastid = $_POST["lastid"];
    if (!$lastid) {
        $array["error"] = "something  is wrong";
    } else {
        $query = $db->query("select * from veri where id>$lastid ORDER  by id DESC ");
        if (mysqli_affected_rows()) {
            while ($row = $query->fetch_object()) {
    $array["data"]='<li id="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->text.'</li>';
            }
        } else {
            $array["error"] = " there is no new record";
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
}
?>
```

Comment: Using this code you may get only last inserted row instead of all new inserted rows, right?

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen that isn't happening with the code you've put in this question? Please edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 1):

Your `setInverval()` accepts a **callback function** as first parameter. You passed a string. It should be:

```
setInterval(ajaxLoad, 5000);
```

And also, remove the `$` from the `$ajaxLoad` definition. It's JavaScript, not PHP. In case that you would want to prepend the `$` to your variable, you must also use that variable along with the `$` like so:

```
$variable = 5;
console.log($variable); // prints 5 to the console
```

However, it is absolutely **bad practice** since you will get confused as to whether you are using PHP or JS.

Here also you did a mistake. As per the current code you may get only last record inserted instead of all new inserted records because you are not concatenating the records. This is one way to solve it:

```
<?php

require "config.php";

if ($_POST) 
{

    $lastid = $_POST["lastid"];
    if (!$lastid) 
    {
        $array["error"] = "something  is wrong";
    } 
    else 
    {
        $query = $db->query("select * from veri where id>$lastid ORDER  by id DESC ");
        if (mysqli_affected_rows()) 
        {
            $new_rows = "";
            while ($row = $query->fetch_object()) 
            {
               $new_rows .= '<li id="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->text.'</li>';

            }
            $array["data"]=$new_rows;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $array["error"] = " there is no new record";
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
}
?>
```